# Variables changing in Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this loop which calls for some info from an API, and then loops through it to add it to a simple array.

```
Promise.all(promisses.map(o => API.functionName(o))).then((p) => {
    var i = startingDate;
    p.forEach(res =>{
        res.forEach(function(value) {
            rankExport.push({
                "teamName" : value.team.name,
                "teamId": value.team.id,
                "position" : value.place,
                "points" : value.points,
                "posChange" : value.change,
                "rankDay" : i.getDate(),
                "rankMonth" : i.getMonth() + 1,
                "rankYear" : i.getFullYear(),
                "date" : i,
            });
        });
        i = add_weeks(i,1)
    });
    saveRankings(rankExport, i);
})
```

This is the add_weeks function:

```
function add_weeks(date, n)  {
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + (n * 7)));      
};
```

One of the key datapoints is the date, which I'm saving in the array as a day, month, year and complete date.

Problem is, this is the outcome I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    teamName: 'Team',
    teamId: 6665,
    position: 1,
    points: 1000,
    posChange: 0,
    rankDay: 27,
    rankMonth: 1,
    rankYear: 2020,
    date: 2020-02-03T03:00:00.000Z
  },
```

There are immediately two problems:

1- There are two different dates: 27/01/2020 and 03/02/2020 which are a week apart. But why? They are coming from the same variable (i).

2- The dates are shifted a week (should be startingDate = 20/01/2020), which is confusing given that my add_weeks formula should be performed after the loops since they aren't asynchronous, right?

Help! Thanks =)

Comment: Follow your logic, exactly when and how many times are you expecting add_weeks() to be called?  It's impossible to tell why you have the add_weeks() function at all from your question and you don't say what its use is or when you expect it to be called or why.  Also just a note, but that outcome isn't valid JSON because there aren't quotes around the date.

Comment: Hey @JasonGoemaat. It's meant to be called every time res.forEach finishes looping, since then we would be grabbing the next p values which are from the following week.

Comment: Are the requests by week as well?  If you are creating one request per week it might make more sense to store that as part of the object that gets returned.  I.e. "var dt = new Date(); var myPromise = request('/getdata/${dt}').then(response => ({dt, response}));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is in your add_weeks() function which isn't shown.  If you call something like `setYear()` on your date object it will modify the date in place.  I'm betting your add_weeks() function doesn't properly copy the date.  See this code:

```js
var i = new Date();
var a = {date: i};
i = new Date();
var b = {date: i};
i.setYear(1999);
var c = {date: i};
console.log(JSON.stringify({ a, b, c }, null, 2));
```

Result is b also shows 1999 because setYear() modified the date:

```
{
  "a": {
    "date": "2020-09-03T20:34:18.284Z"
  },
  "b": {
    "date": "1999-09-03T20:34:18.284Z"
  },
  "c": {
    "date": "1999-09-03T20:34:18.284Z"
  }
}
```

To fix that, in your add_weeks() function create a new date, ala:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var newDate = new Date(dt.getTime());
newDate.setYear(1999);
console.log(dt, newDate);
-- shows different dates
```

Comment: Added the function to the main post for context. EDIT: I see, maybe the add_weeks formula is changing the date in i. But why are the dates different when its pushing the same i?

Comment: Did that fix the issue?  It's impossible to know for sure, that was my best guess.  When you create the object to push into `rankExport` you are calling like `getDate()` which returns the day *of the i value at that time*  and setting `date` to i.  For the next response if you add a week to `i`, that would change the value of `date` for the old records because they would refer to the same date, but since `getDate()` returned a number, that value would be what it was when the object was created and added to `rankExport`

Comment: Does that help or are you asking something else with *"But why are the dates different when its pushing the same i?"*

Comment: Hey @jason-goemaat. Thanks for the replies. Yes, this did the trick. It makes sense to me that the variable containing the date was being changed around unintentionally. What I'm still baffled by is how it is possible that it had 2 different values in the same push(). There are 4 lines where I'm taking information from the same variable (i), there isn't anything modifying the variable in between, why is the 4th line ("date" : i) looking at a different i than the rest?

Comment: `date` is a reference to a date object that is mutable meaning it can change.  It's like if you had a `person` object with a `name`.  If you use the same object, they all refer to the same thing in memory and changing a property on one affects every place that object is referred to.  [*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/zacrfm9y/)

Comment: @MarianoMolina Here's an updated fiddle showing better what is happening.  The 'firstName' is different for each object because it is a string value, while 'name.first' all refer to the same name object: [*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/zacrfm9y/1/)

Comment: Hey Jason, right, this makes sense. I think. I guess in my example i.getDate() is stored as a string, and therefore isn't changed, but the "date" : i is stored as the variable itself so can be modified by changes to that variable later. Re-reading your first comment makes sense now. Thanks!